# Modeling Non-Stationary Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, autoregressive, stationarity

Data set: response and predictors are all non-stationary, time series variables

After performing Box-Cox transformations and testing a variety of power transformations on each variable, the non-stationarity still exists. Linear models have therefore been discarded in favor of autoregressive models.

To construct ARIMA models, the variables were differenced, but the acf and pacf plots still have bars that exceed the significance bounds at all difference levels.

What statistical approach is next in line? Nonlinear transformations? Nonlinear models?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data and/or plots so to illustrate your question? This would help us to get better picture of your problem.

Comment: If the ACF and PACF bars did not exceed the significance bounds, there would be no use for the ARIMA model. Having significant bars is thus desirable if you want to proceed with an ARIMA model.